# right approach of custom view implementing

Tags: android, view, custom-controls, onclicklistener

I need to implement such a element - TextView of predefined size with white border line at the bottom. Inside of the TextView a button with predefined style and size should be. TextView shouldn'y be clickable and button should be. I see some possible solutions:

1) implement TableLayout and put all my buttons into the table's row. But there's not nice solution - my layout becomes too long. So I think about another solution.

2) make my element as a custom view. But the problem is that I need to use a lot of these elements through my app and I need use onClickListener to each of them. I know how to implement onClick() method for all items but how I can use singular onClick() method for each of the item? And how should I build this custom view  - should it be extending from RelativeLayout, where TextView and Button with defined properties should be put?

I also thought about  using for the button, but in this case my TextView will be also clickable.

Tell me please what approach is less complicated and more convenient.

Comment: Why don't you make a LinearLayout containting a TextView and a Button?

Comment: I have a lot of similar UI elements in my application and my layouts become very long, so I decided create one custom item, which can be used in all parts of app and properties of which can be easily modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another way if solving this issue. I put buttons and other control elements into the TableLayout with predefined TableRow style. In this case I do not need implement TextView and borders margins which I need I build with corresponding TableRow style.